# vue.js unit test v-slot with function call

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, bootstrap-vue

I use bootstrap-vue for the vue.js css framework and decided to test the desired component. This component uses b-table and has a v-slot with a call function.

```html
<template>
    <b-table
        striped
        bordered
        :items="items"
        :fields="$t('pages.events.show.users.fields')"
    >
        <template v-slot:cell(name)="{ item }">
            <b-avatar :src="item.avatar" class="mr-2" />
            <span v-text="item.name" />
        </template>
    </b-table>
</template>
```

and I'm writing a simple test for this component:

```js
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import EventUsersTable from "./EventUsersTable.vue";

/* #region  Test setup */
const factory = () => {
    return shallowMount(EventUsersTable, {
        mocks: {
            $t: jest.fn()
        },
        stubs: {
            BTable: true
        }
    });
};
/* #endregion */

describe("EventUsersTable.vue", () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => (wrapper = factory()));

    test("should render component", () => {
        expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

and i have error with this content: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined"`

for write test for this component i need fix this problem.

And I have a problem with the vue unit test document, they are very limited and with few examples.
If anyone knows a source that has more examples and scenarios for vue language tests, thank you for introducing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inquiring, I came up with a solution that, using mount and adding the main component, was able to solve my problem.

```js
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import { BTable } from "bootstrap-vue";
import EventUsersTable from "./EventUsersTable.vue";

/* #region  Test setup */
const factory = () => {
    return mount(EventUsersTable, {
        mocks: {
            $t: jest.fn()
        },
        stubs: {
            BTable
        }
    });
};
/* #endregion */

describe("EventUsersTable.vue", () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => (wrapper = factory()));

    // FIXME: fix this bug for render component
    test("should render component", () => {
        expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```